# Portlet in LIferay not saving to database throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, mysql, liferay, portlet

I've made up my mind to ask this question after an hour of debugging in eclipse and not deciding what may be the cause of the error.

The thing is I'm making a portlet that saves some data to mysql and it's not working. The portlet deploys and shows fine in the Control Panel, but it doesn't save in the database. When I debug I can see that the values are populated alright, but for some reason, when I finally call LocalServiceUtil to actually save the data, the portal throws an `InvocationTargetException` in the file `portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/LiferayPortlet.java` of Liferay source. The error says that "There are no actions associated with the resource edu.cide.portal.directorio.model.Empleado" (id=20241) and also that there are "errors during the evaluation" so I'm figuring somehow the action isn't being called alright. But it's strange because my code is really simple, I have an EmpleadoLocalServiceImpl
like so:

```
public Empleado addEmpleado(Empleado registro, long userId) throws SystemException, 
PortalException
{
Empleado nuevoEmpleado =  empleadoPersistence.create(counterLocalService.increment(Empleado.class.getName()));
resourceLocalService.addResources(nuevoEmpleado.getCompanyId(), nuevoEmpleado.getGroupId(),   userId, Empleado.class.getName(), nuevoEmpleado.getPrimaryKey(), false, true, true);
nuevoEmpleado.setNombre(registro.getNombre());
nuevoEmpleado.setApellidoPat(registro.getApellidoPat());
nuevoEmpleado.setExtension(registro.getExtension());
nuevoEmpleado.setCorreo(registro.getCorreo());
nuevoEmpleado.setGroupId(registro.getGroupId());
nuevoEmpleado.setCompanyId(registro.getCompanyId());
return empleadoPersistence.update(nuevoEmpleado, false);
}
```

and then a portlet class like so:

```
public class AdminDirectorio extends MVCPortlet {

public void addEmpleado(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
   ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    Empleado empleado = new EmpleadoImpl();
    empleado.setNombre(ParamUtil.getString(request, "nombreEmpleado"));
    empleado.setApellidoPat(ParamUtil.getString(request, "apellidoPrimEmpleado"));
    empleado.setApellidoMat(ParamUtil.getString(request, "apellidoSegEmpleado"));
    empleado.setExtension(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "extensionEmpleado"));
   empleado.setCorreo(ParamUtil.getString(request, "correoEmpleado"));

   if(Validator.isNull(ParamUtil.getString(request, "nombreEmpleado")) || Validator.isNull(ParamUtil.getString(request, "apellidoPrimEmpleado")) 
   || Validator.isNull(ParamUtil.getString(request, "apellidoSegEmpleado")) || Validator.isNull(ParamUtil.getString(request, "apellidoSegEmpleado"))        
   || Validator.isNull(ParamUtil.getString(request, "correoEmpleado")) || !Validator.isEmailAddress(ParamUtil.getString(request, "correoEmpleado"))
   || !Validator.isDigit(ParamUtil.getString(request, "extensionEmpleado"))
   ) {
   SessionErrors.add(request, "campos-invalidos");
   }
   else {
   EmpleadoLocalServiceUtil.addEmpleado(empleado, themeDisplay.getUserId());
   SessionMessages.add(request, "empleado-guardado-exitosamente");
   }
   }
```

Can someone please help me because I don't have a clue as to what's happening?
I also think I must mention that I see that the values for groupId and companyId are as follows: 
_groupId 0 
_IdEmpleado 0 
_companyId 0
where IdEmpleado is my primary key on the mysql table, I don't know if that's alright. I'm developing in a Liferay portal without any comunity or user groups defined

So I added a try catch block to my method that prints the stack trace and it is as follows:

```
com.liferay.portal.ResourceActionsException: There are no actions associated with the resource edu.cide.portal.directorio.model.Empleado
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.validate(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:1097)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.addResources(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:857)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceLocalServiceImpl.addResources(ResourceLocalServiceImpl.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.addResources(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cide.portal.directorio.service.impl.EmpleadoLocalServiceImpl.addEmpleado(EmpleadoLocalServiceImpl.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy417.addEmpleado(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cide.portal.directorio.service.EmpleadoLocalServiceUtil.addEmpleado(EmpleadoLocalServiceUtil.java:282)
    at edu.cide.portal.directorio.portlet.AdminDirectorio.addEmpleado(AdminDirectorio.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:148)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:247)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:78)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:649)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:312)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doProcessAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:402)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:110)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:75)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:356)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If it's of any help, I still think the relevant part is the first message in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what the problem was, it looks like I had repeated code in the LocalServiceImpl part, so I was calling twice addEmpleado, or sort of it. After removing the method addEmpleado that went like this:

```
public Empleado addEmpleado(Empleado registro, long userId) throws SystemException, 
PortalException
{

Empleado nuevoEmpleado = empleadoPersistence.create(counterLocalService.increment(Empleado.class.getName()));
resourceLocalService.addResources(nuevoEmpleado.getCompanyId(), nuevoEmpleado.getGroupId(), userId, Empleado.class.getName(), nuevoEmpleado.getPrimaryKey(), false, true, true);
nuevoEmpleado.setNombre(registro.getNombre());
nuevoEmpleado.setApellidoPat(registro.getApellidoPat());
nuevoEmpleado.setExtension(registro.getExtension());
nuevoEmpleado.setCorreo(registro.getCorreo());
nuevoEmpleado.setGroupId(registro.getGroupId());
nuevoEmpleado.setCompanyId(registro.getCompanyId());

return empleadoPersistence.update(nuevoEmpleado, false);
}
```

entirely from the LocalServiceImpl class, it worked by only calling LocalServiceUtil `addEmpleado(edu.cide.portal.directorio.model.Empleado empleado) it worked and it's saving alright in the DB. Funny I tried to follow exactly the "Liferay in Action" book and it only lead to confusion. 
Thanks for your support anyway.